# Laravel: resolving the n + 1 problem that has raw query or custom function

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a Laravel application. I am having a bit of a problem with querying the data.

This is my database schema.

I have a users table with the following fields.

```
users
- id
- name
- email
- password
```

Then I have the transactions table with the following fields.

```
transactions
- id
- amount
- user_id
- type
- created_at
```

As you can see transactions table has the user_id as a foreign key to the users table.

This is the User model.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

This is the Transaction model

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to get a user's transactions with additional column and conditional checking. Normally, if I wanted to get a user's transactions, I would do something like this.

```
$user->transactions()->get()
```

But I want to get an extra column for each row, for each row, I would like to get the sum of the amount of transactions until the created_at of transactions of the current row.

If I have to write a function for the single record, it would be something like this.

```
function totalAmountUntil($user, $date)
{
   return $user->transactions->where('transactions.created_at', '<=', $date)->sum('transactions.amount');
}
```

I need to apply that to each row in the query based on the created_at of the transactions also resolving the n+1 problem. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use withCount for this :

```php
User::withCount([
'transactions as transactions_amount_sum' => function($query) use ($date){
     $query->where('created_at', '<=', $date)
           ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount)'));
}
])->get();
```